# In what situations should we use function signature void *(*)()?

Tags: c, function, pointers, signature, void

This question comes up in my mind when I look at the synopsis of pthread_create, which is:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

I don't understand why the third parameter has to be that complex. Its purpose is just for passing in a function address. So why don't they use

```
void (*start_routine)(void *)
```

or even

```
void (start_routine)(void *)
```

In general, in what situations should we use a function signature like the third parameter above?

Comment: In situations when you want the function passed to be able to return any sort of data via pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start_routine takes a `void*` to allow the thread starter to pass some arbitrary data to the new thread. It returns a `void*` so that the thread can return a meaningful exit code to the caller (instead of explicitly having to invoke `pthread_exit` from the thread function).

Note that your second suggestion (`void (start_routine)(void*)` is not a function pointer, and so isn't an option for a parameter to `pthread_create` or any other function at all.

Comment: I see. So it is the purpose of returning an exit code that they use void* in front of the function pointer. Thank you very much.

Comment: `void start_routine(void *)` as a function parameter is converted to a function pointer (unless I'm badly mistaken).

Comment: really? is it implicit converted? like parkovski answered below, I thought it is not even allowed to be parameter type.

Comment: Just tested on GCC and it does accept it and treat it as a function pointer. However, it still returns `void` instead of `void *` and using the * is the more widely understood way to do it.

Comment: "Note that your second suggestion...is not a function pointer."  That is not true:  as a function parameter type, `void (*)(void*)` and `void()(void*)` are the same:  the function type is implicitly transformed into its corresponding function-pointer type, in the same way that an array type is implicitly transformed into its corresponding element pointer type.

Answer (score 3):

C function pointer syntax is notoriously ugly and hard to understand. Basically the answer is that it has to be that way because that's how the designers of C decided to do it.

`void *(*start_routine) (void *)` refers to a pointer to a function, taking one parameter of type `void *`, and returning a `void *`.

The first example you gave, `void (*start_routine)(void *)` is also a function pointer, and also takes a `void *` parameter, but returns nothing.

The other example, `void (start_routine)(void *)`
 isn't a function pointer, and it doesn't return anything. The parenthesis don't really serve any purpose there, and it would be the same as writing `void start_routine(void *)` which I'm fairly sure is not allowed as a parameter type.

Edit: that one actually is allowed as a parameter, but it's not as widely used and still has the wrong return type.

Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void%20%2a%28%2astart_routine%29%20%28void%20%2a%29) has to say about that:

> declare start_routine as pointer to function (pointer to void) returning pointer to void

The first `void *` means that the function returns a generic pointer. `(*start_routine)` means that the parameter is a pointer (to a function). `(void *)` means that the function takes a single argument, a generic pointer.